# Валидация json не верна

Tags: python, json

Создаю json, но не понимаю в чем моя ошибка:
Валидатора выдают ошибку:

```
Error: Parse error on line 1:
[{'date': '4 НОЯБРЯ', 
--^
Expecting 'STRING', '}', got 'undefined'
```

JSON:

```
[{
'date': '4 НОЯБРЯ',
'histories': [{
    'image': 'https://static.qiwi.com/img/providers/logoBig/1963_l.png',
    'name': 'Перевод на карту Visa ************6693',
    'Сумма платежа': '849',
    'Комиссия': '66,98',
    'Итого': '915,98'
}, {
    'image': 'https://static.qiwi.com/img/providers/logoBig/1_l.png',
    'name': 'МТС 9872487132'
}]
}, {
    'date': '3 НОЯБРЯ',
    'histories': [{
        'image': None,
        'name': 'QIWI Кошелек',
        'Сумма платежа': '926,45',
        'Комиссия': '0',
        'Итого': '926,45'
    }]
}]
```

Comment: В стандарте JSON ясно написано, что строки должны заключаться в двойные кавычки.

Comment: Строки должны быть в двойных кавычках, и значение None нужно закрывать кавычками тоже

Comment: Вместо значения `None` должен быть `null`.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev а как null в python указать, там же None

Comment: Так вы определитесь, у вас JSON или структура данных Python.

Comment: Спасибо, я просто библиотеку json не применил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас там какой-то `None` есть и кавычки одинарные. Если поправить должно стать валидным.

```
import json
your_json = ''' ... '''
print json.dumps(your_json)

# .... "image": null, .....

w = {"a": None}
print json.loads(json.dumps(w)) < --- None - null - None
# {"a": None}
```